# Shocking result after see my application stress test in JMeter

Tags: testing, jmeter

After stress test one of my application I get this result

[image]

How can I reduce this error?Have any suggestion ? I made my application by core php.

Comment: There are many reasons why this might occur. With no code posted it's impossible for us to comment.

Comment: This is a huge application how I will post this code?I just need a proposal how can I solve it ?

Comment: Here's an analogy: I drove my car today, but it would only do 25mph. How can I fix this? Now do you see why yours is a bad question?

Comment: That means problem in car not in road ? If you say problem in car I will repair my car if you say problem in road I will repair rood.My confusion is can it happen for JMeter setting mistake,like as cache or cookie setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this to start: -

1. Profile your code while the test is running to see where the bottlenecks are. You might use a profiling tool or sprinkle timestamp logs depending on what suits your needs.
2. Run the tests with sub-units of your application to isolate where the bottlenecks are.
3. Run pinpoint tests that target specific areas to identify problematic areas.

Comment: That was a government project,and a huge pressure was on me to solve this problem.Full night I have spend time on this problem.thanks a lot.